# Javascript: View XML that was retrieved from an external source

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, json

Ok, this piece of code:

```
    http_request = false;
    http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (http_request.overrideMimeType) {
        http_request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
    }
    if (!http_request){return false;}
    http_request.open('GET', realXmlUrl, true);
    http_request.send(null);
    xmlDoc = http_request.responseXML;
```

seems to successfully get an external xml file.

Butwhen I try to view it... by doing something like `alert(xmlDoc);` it wont let me see the actual xml file ;(

how do I see the actual XML file?

Thanks!
R

Comment: What does http_request.responseText contain?

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for! Can you write the above in an answer so I can select your response as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check http_request.responseText. As long as reponseXML isn't null, it should be a Document object and can be interacted with as such.